# How to wait on a button for user input in order to set a variable

Tags: java, android, android-studio, button

I am writing a class that has certain variables that don't need to be set except in certain fringe cases.  As such, I am working on writing a requestVariable() method that asks for user input to set that variable when it is needed.  However, I am struggling to figure out how to wait for that input before moving on.  Let me show you what I have.

```html
SkillApplication AR_D_Atk_Def_1_app = (Unit) -> {
            if (Unit.getAttackStatus() != com.codecademy.myapplication.Unit.AttackStatus.DEFENDER) {
                return;
            }
            else {
                // Make sure structuresAR is set
                Unit.setStructuresAR(requestVariable( /* some parameters */ );

                int X;

                if (Unit.getStructuresAR() >= 5) {
                    X = 4;
                }
                else if (Unit.getStructuresAR() == 4) {
                    X = 3;
                }
                else if (Unit.getStructuresAR() == 3) {
                    X = 2;
                }
                else {
                    X = 1;
                }

                Unit.addCombatAtk(X);
                Unit.addCombatDef(X);
            }
        };
```

This is a lambda function for a certain skill's application.  If this skill needs to be applied, it will run this lambda function.  This is one of the fringe cases where the member "structuresAR" of Unit needs to be used.  It's very rarely used, and rather than having the user set it every time, I have it set in this lambda function.

```html
VariableRequest<Integer> requestInteger = (VariableRequest<Integer>) (questionMessage, choices, layout) -> {
            final Integer[] retVal = new Integer[1];

            TextView questionView = new TextView(layout.getContext());
            questionView.setText(questionMessage);

            EditText textEntry = new EditText(layout.getContext());
            textEntry.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

            Button submitButton = new Button(layout.getContext());
            submitButton.setText("Submit");

            layout.addView(questionView);
            layout.addView(textEntry);
            layout.addView(submitButton);

            submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    retVal[0] = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(textEntry.getText()));
                }
            });


        };
```

Here's what I have written so far for that function.  It sets a question, options, and submit button to a layout that updates a return value with what is in the entry box when a button is clicked.

This problem is, this just keeps going.  The rest of whatever I've written will be run while the onClickListener is still there, and I don't know how to wait until that's been clicked.  I'm coming from C++ knowledge where just writing cin >> *variable* would pause and wait for you to enter.  I'm trying to replicate that with a button.

There's also other problems I can spot with this such as getting the layout from inside a static method, but I struggle to come up with another method as I'm very new to Android development.

Comment: You don't "wait". You are using an event-driven library and instead respond to events.

Comment: Are you saying there is absolutely no way to wait then?  I'd have to completely restructure a lot of things then.

Comment: Yup, that's how it works. Whatever calculations you wish to perform after the user clicks that button need to be inside that onClick method (or, more likely, that onClick method ends up invoking a method that does this). Note that you can't block or take too long; fire up a separate thread or use SwingWorker if you need that.